# Scss styling changes are not reflectct

Tags: html, css, sass

I am new to SCSS. I am working on a python web application. I have an issue that the changes in SCSS are not reflected. Only the changes in CSS file are reflected.

I checked online and created a mapping file:

```
{"version":3,"sourceRoot":"","sources":["index.scss"],"names":[],"mappings":"AACE;EACE","file":"index.css"}
```

I still very confused. Do I need to run some command to map the SCSS to css whenever I change the scss file? If yes, what command should I run?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure your workflow compiles the scss files to css everytime you start your application.